# Manin's algebraic geometry textbook?

Tags: reference-request, ag.algebraic-geometry

Context: I recently chatted with  a postdoc from russia, and we somehow got on the topic of learning mathematics and textbooks, and he told me about a wonderful textbook by Yuri Manin, on algebraic geometry which was written at the beginning of the seventies and wildely used for a long time in the former SU. He was so full of praise that I decided to check it out.

Now the problem I checked  our library catalog and amazon.com and can't find anything that I can identify as this AG-textbook.

Question:
So does this book exists? What's it's title? Was it maybe not translated?.
Q2:
If anyone has anything interesting to say about the book this would also be appreciated.

PS: I also speak german so if you know a german translation please also post.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do you mean these:

- [Lectures on algebraic geometry. Part I: Affine schemes](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=284434) (Russian)
- [Lectures in algebraic geometry. Part II: The $K$-functor in algebraic geometry](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=422277) (Russian, [English version](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=265355))

Apparently the second is based on *Théorie globale des intersections et théorème de Riemann-Roch* SGA 6, Exp. 0.

Here are some djvu scans of the Russian versions:

- [Лекции по алгебраической геометрии. Часть 1. Аффинные схемы](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/ru/library/books/Manin_ch1_1970ru.djvu),
- [Лекции по алгебраической геометрии. Часть 2. К-функтор в алгебраической геометрии](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/ru/library/books/Manin_ch2_1971ru.djvu)

Comment: Thanks I guess that's exactly the book/lecture notes. Does anyone know whether a translation exists?

Comment: Yes, at least  for  the second. I have a copy of 
"Lectures on the K-functor..." in English 
from Russian Math. Surveys vol 24, 1969.

Comment: I have both, the affine schemes , but some Moscow people told me that there was another version which is bigger than affine schemes volume and has no intersection with K-theory chapters in UMN. I am not sure if this is true.

Comment: thanks to both of you for your comments. 
@Thanks Donu this was really helpful, sadly the article is 60$, I will try to check if we have an institutional subscription.
@Zoran This sounds interesting too, where did you get your's from?

Comment: @sisn: "K-functor..." from Russ. Math. Surv.: http://justpasha.org/math/links/files/manin/lectures-on-k-functor.djvu

Comment: Thanks for your answer together with the helpful comments it was exactly what I was looking for- sorry that it took me so long to accept it, I was away for two weeks and forgot my labtob with all the login details :-)

Answer (score 11):

There now is a book by Manin *Introduction to the theory of schemes* (Translated from the Russian, edited and with a preface by Dimitry Leites) recently [published](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-74316-5) by Springer based on Manin's lectures on algebraic geometry mentioned in David Roberts' post.

Answer (score 8):

Hope this helps:
[Manin's lectures on algebraic geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89530/manins-lectures-on-algebraic-geometry/96884#96884)

Its the first part of Manin's 1966-1968 course (the one Zoran mentioned), chapters 1-26 . It's been scanned just recently.

Comment: The link given by Dmitry on the answer behind the link here is broken.