# Manin's lectures on algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

In 1966-1968 Yuri Manin gave a 2 year lecture course in algebraic geometry at Moscow State University. The course starts from scratch and culminates in the proof of the Riemann-Roch theorem following SGA6 with some simplifications. The course was subsequently published by the Moscow University Press in two parts. Part 2 contained the proof of the Riemann-Roch theorem and Part 1 the preliminary material. (Part 2 also appeared as a paper in the Russian Mathematical Surveys.)

However, the version of Part 1 that I have has only chapters 1 to 15, and in Part 2 Manin makes references to chapters 25 and 22 of Part 1. This is why I would like to ask whether any more of Part 1 exists, apart from chapters 1-15, and if so, whether it has been made publicly available.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you read Russian?

Comment: Yes, I can read Russian.

Comment: Have you seen this question and answers to it?
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/72068/manins-algebraic-geometry-textbook

Comment: @Mahdi: That is the notes OP mentions. The first part goes up to Section 15. 

Answer (score 5):

http://free-books.us.to/book/index.php?md5=ed3962d4a7d7104ec7f28daf6d99dab1

I've uploaded the scan of complete 1966-1968 lectures. The site doesn't seem to work pretty well, so in case you're unable to download it I can send it by email.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I am interested in the note but I cannot find your email address.
I would rather make this as a comment, but my reputation point is still below 50.
If you read this posting, please send your note to jazzpiano3@gmail.com.
I would appreciate it.

Comment: You could upload it on Google Drive and make it public.

Comment: The link doesn't work. Could you send those notes to me?

Comment: (Click on my name to find my email address)

Comment: The link in this answer is broken. Perhaps someone who got a copy could act on Chandan's suggestion?

Comment: Sorry but I have to report this answer since it became misleading.